# Проверка синтаксиса введенной формулы на JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Задача достаточно проста: есть поле input и кнопка. В поле вводится формула вида `y = sin(x)` и после нажатия на кнопку требуется эту формулу проверить на правильность, чтоб не было например `y = sin(x`. Есть ли какие-либо средства для реализации такой задачи?

Comment: Для начала нужно определиться с набором правил, по котором отличаются правильные формулы от неправильных

Comment: Любая синтаксически верная формула должна считается правильной

Comment: Для начала нужно определиться с набором правил, по которым определяется синтаксическая корректность формул